# Graphing a mathematical equation in AS2

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, flash

I'm trying to write a simple AS2 script that graphs a second degree polynomial by plotting the first 100 points of the equation,i made a red dot,converted it to a symbol called `point`,created a new frame and inserted the following code:

```
var X:Number=0;
var Y:Number=0;
var a:Number=3;
var b:Number=3;
var c:Number=3;
var i:Number=0;

function func(X,Y,a,b,c){
Y=a*X*X+b*Y+c
}
while(X=O,X<100,++X,i=O,i<100,++i){
attachMovie("point", "pont+i", 0, {_x:X, _y:Y});
}


func(X,Y,a,b,c)
```

The idea is that this code would start creating instances of the red dot respectively named `pont0,pont2,pont3,...,pont99` but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.
The error log shows nothing,and neither does the .swf file,what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in `while` usage.It has only one argument - condition statement

try something like this

```
  var X:Number=0;
  var Y:Number=0;
  var a:Number=3;
  var b:Number=3;
  var c:Number=3;
  var i:Number=0;

  function func(X,Y,a,b,c){
        return a*X*X+b*Y+c
  }

  while(i<100){
        attachMovie("pont", "pont+i", i, {_x:X, _y:func(X,Y,a,b,c)});
        i++;
        X++;
  }
```

Comment: sorry i couldn't reply earlier,but it's the same result,empty log and S W F.

Comment: are you sure that you have symbol in library with linkage of 'pont'?

Comment: you could upload some example, it will make things more clear instanly

Comment: as i thought your symbol in library doesn't have identifier. open symbol properties in library -> advanced and enter some id in `identifier` field. with script i've provided it should be `pont`

Comment: that worked,thank you very much,but i thought i gave it an id with the attach movie function!?

Comment: `attachMovie()` have 4 params. first one - linkage of library item as `String`, second - name and identifier of created movie as `String` (by this identifier you can lately access created MCs), third one is `depth` as `Number` - it should be unique for every MCs you create (its work like the layers), and last one (optional) - properties of created MC as `Object`

Comment: thank you very much,i hope everyone learn from this thread like i did!